# Scrapbook Graphics

Tags: fonts, copyright

I have been using Photoshop/Illustrator to design my own graphic scrapbook logos and designs. I create my own styles from tutorials, but I do use the tools & fonts that come with the program. My question now is how can I use these fonts when I try to sell my scrapbook graphics as kits? Do I have to learn how to create my own fonts as well?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a font to create a logo and then convert said logo to paths and that is typically fine. In that scenario you aren't distributing the font itself...you're distributing some shapes based on the font.

If, on the other hand, you are distributing an *editable* logo--meaning you want to allow the end-user the ability to modify the text using a specific font--then you will have to distribute the font file with your product.

Whether you are allowed to distribute the font file with your commercial project is going to depend on the license you have with the font foundry. Most default licenses do *not* allow you to redistribute the typeface. You would need to contact the font foundry and ask them what kind of license you'd need (if they offer it) to do what you want to do.

Some exceptions would be open source typefaces. Open source licenses typically grant you the right to redistribute provided you retain attribution/credits with the font file.

Comment: No editable logo, simply using adding the words to a design and embellishing them, then selling the finished product as a graphic. So, I am to assume I am okay in doing this then?

Comment: @Debbie in most cases, yes. A few exceptions (such as House Industry's typefaces which have a few more restrictions on selling products that have used their typefaces)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been searching for fonts that have open licenses for SIL open font license for commercial use to see if I can find something comparable. Seems a heck of a lot easier all the way around for my needs. Thank you for your help!